# Read Access Violation Exception on reading information from a PE nt_header

Tags: c++, exception, memory-management, access-violation

Here i want to get ntheader info from a PE image (Image type is `unsigned char array` or `string` then converting to `unsigned char array`):

```
IMAGE_DOS_HEADER * DOSHeader = PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(Image);
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS * NtHeader = PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS(DWORD(Image) + DOSHeader->e_lfanew);
```

But when i want to use that info:

```
DWORD NtSignature = 0;
NtSignature = NtHeader->Signature;
```

It throws:
 [ReadAccessViolation. NtHeader was 0x......](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFBh7.png) 
And this is debugger [Locals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzKvD.png)

Is the problem with the PE image or a bug in code ?

I am not trying to violate anything. This code was working formerly, Now it throws exception with any PE image.

Comment: What's the type of `Image`?

Comment: @hlt `unsigned char array`

Comment: Is that the file path of the image, or its actual contents?

Comment: Image source is embedded in the code. That `Image` is something like `unsigned char pesource[27136] = {
 0x4D, 0x5A, 0x90, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }`. Yes it is the actual content.